# How to retrieve similarly named csv files and create dataframes with them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple csv files with similar names in numeric order (nba_1, nba_2, etc).  They are all formatted the same as far as column names and dtypes.  Instead of manually pulling each one in individually to a dataframe `(nba_1 = pd.read_csv('/nba_1.csv'))` is there a way to write a `for` loop or something like it to pull them in and name them?  I think the basic framework would be something like:

```
for i in range(1, 6):
    nba_i = pd.read_csv('../nba_i.csv')
```

Beyond that, I do not know the particulars.  Once I pull them in I will be performing the same actions on each of them (deleting and formating the same columns) so I would also want to iterate through them there.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Comment: What are you trying to do with the files is the better question.

Comment: Mixing strings and numbers to build a string is a job for "str.format()"

Comment: use 'glob'...! that should be it

Comment: What I am doing to each one after I am pulling them in is say which columns I want to keep in the dataframe ```nba_1=nba_1[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']] then doing some work on a date column (when it comes in it is formatted as a string and fixing some other stuff).  Once I have done that on each of them, I will be combining them into one dataframe.  I think I am also set on doing that last step.  I just want to simplify pulling them in and formatting them.  There are only six files so it would not be a huge thing to write the code six times but if I can be cleaner and more efficient then why not.

Answer (score 1):

- I think your real question is how to get all the files into a dataframe
- Use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), part of the standard library, to work with your files.

  - [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)
- Since your `csv` files are the same, as you stated in the question, it would be more efficient to combine them all into a single dataframe and then clean the data all at once.

  - It's less efficient to clean each dataframe separately, and then combine them

### To get a single, combined dataframe

```py
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

p = Path(r'c:\some_path_to_files')  # set your path
files = p.glob('nba*.csv')  # find your files

# It was stated, all the files are the same format, so create one dataframe
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file) for file in files])
```

- `[pd.read_csv(file) for file in files]` is a list comprehension, which creates a dataframe of each file.
- `pd.concat` combines all the files in the list

### To get separate dataframes:

- create a `dict` of dataframes
- each `key` of the `dict` will be a filename

```py
p = Path(r'c:\some_path_to_files')  # set your path
files = p.glob('nba*.csv')  # find your files

df_dict = dict()
for file in files:
    df_dict[file.stem] = pd.read_csv(file)
```

#### Using `df_dict`:

```py
df_dict.keys()  # to show you all the keys

df_dict[filename]  # to access a specific dataframe

# after cleaning the individual dataframes in df_dict, they can be combined
df_final = pd.concat([value for value in df_dict.values()])
```

Comment: Eventually I want to get them into the same dataframe but I cannot do that to start with.  They are each for different years.  When I pull them in the date column is a string and is MMDD with no separator (ex: ```0526, 0617```).  What I have done on the one dataframe I have been experimenting on to get replicable code is taking the string date and adding a ```/``` in the middle (```05/26```) and then appending on a year. (to be continued in the next comment)

Comment: The data is for individual NBA seasons so not all of the dates have the same year.  October to December are one year and January to June are another year.  If I combine them to one file to start with I think it will treat all of my 0526's the same when they each represents a different year and each csv will two year numbers in it (the 2012 season cover part of 2012 and 2013) that I need to add in.  That is why I need to clean each one of them individually before merging.  I am open to hearing a way to merge them if you can get think get over the hurdle I think I have.

Comment: That makes sense, just use the second option to create a dict of individual dataframes

Answer (score 0):

The Dask library built over Pandas has methods to load multiple csv to single dataframe, at once.